# Mapping to pojo total from list of lists

Tags: java

I need to process my array list and calculate the total that is take from each account balance.
I can't have another data structure as per homework.

```
ArrayList<Customer> = {
{  Forename= Blue, Surname= Red, CustomerId= 2119954221, Age= 98, Accounts= [Account Name = Current Account, Account ID = 1, Accounts Balance = 0.0, Account total = 0.0, Account Name = Current Account, Account ID = 2, Accounts Balance = 0.0, Account total = 0.0] }
{  Forename= Orange, Surname= Yellow, CustomerId= 1448877171, Age= 32, Accounts= [Account Name = Current Account, Account ID = 3, Account Balance = 10000.0, Account total = 10000.0, Account Name = Current Account, Account ID = 4, Account Balance = -100.0, Account total = -100.0, Account Name = Savings Account, Account ID = 26634, Account Balance = 10.0, Account total = 10.0] }
...................
}
```

POJO's

```
class Account {
    private final String accountName;
    private final int accountId;
    private final double accountBalance;
    private double accountTotal;
}

class Customer {
    private final String forename;
    private final String surname;
    private final long customerId;
    private final int age;
    private List<Account> accounts;
}
```

First though was to loop over the list and

```
public static void calculateAccountTotal(){
double total = 0;
        for (Customer c : CUSTOMERS) {
            for (Account a : c.getAccounts()) {
                total += a.getAccountBalance();
                a.setTotal(total);
            }
      }
}
```

This does not work as the previous total is added to the next customer.

A potential solution would be to add an accountKey to the Customer and Account, so I can have a constant in both lists, to check if they match and calculate the total.
Maybe that would stop the addition of balance to the next customer.

I don't think that is a go, tho.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you are trying to obtain the customer balance of all accounts they own.

```
public static void calculateAccountTotal(){
    for (Customer c : CUSTOMERS) {
        double total = 0;
        for (Account a : c.getAccounts()) {
            total += a.getAccountBalance();
        }
        c.setTotal(total);
    }
}
```

Storing the account balance in account would make your account object to hold wrong data. A better option the balance at customer level.

Comment: thank you, I understand now where I was wrong. 
A customer is one and accounts are many.
Still, if I would have wanted to have a variable in each account, as "totalForAllAcounts", how would that be achievable?

Comment: @Scilla We can say that everything is possible but doing that will cause you a lot of trouble. You will need to have a synchronization mechanism in order to make sure that all accounts of a customer have the same value. This gets even trickier in a multi threaded environment where synchronization mechanisms become by far more complex. Because of this the performance of your code will significantly reduce. It's a good idea find EASY ways to avoid side effects in your code. A good place to start would be to use pure functions. Besides those there are many other unmentioned considerations

Comment: your explanation makes sense. thank you taking the time. I suppose my proposed solution "to have a constant in Customer and Account, for synchronization purposes, is what you mean by "synchronization mechanisms"".